# How to filter json data

Tags: json, python-2.7

I just need to save few fields like PublicIpAddress and PrivateIpAddress while omitting everything else in a large json file. How can I do this in Python, is there "jq" like functionality natively. Thank you in advance.

```
[
      {
        "EbsOptimized": false,
        "LaunchTime": "2017-01-10T12:19:30+00:00", 
        "PublicIpAddress": "54.229.28.216",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.2.152"
      },
      {
        "EbsOptimized": false,
        "LaunchTime": "2017-01-10T12:19:30+00:00",
        "PublicIpAddress": "54.229.28.217",
        "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.2.153"
      }
    ]
```

Edit: I need to do this in a python script, not outside of python environment.

Comment: You could try http:[objectpath](//objectpath.org/)

Comment: Not sure about object path, I am new to python. I just need to filter out few son fields from a file.

Comment: Well Python has its own [JSON library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: You may have to convert the JSON into python dictionary and walk through it to get the specific values...

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
import json
json_data = '[
          {
            "EbsOptimized": false,
            "LaunchTime": "2017-01-10T12:19:30+00:00", 
            "PublicIpAddress": "54.229.28.216",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.2.152"
          },
          {
            "EbsOptimized": false,
            "LaunchTime": "2017-01-10T12:19:30+00:00",
            "PublicIpAddress": "54.229.28.217",
            "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.2.153"
          }
        ]'
dict = json.loads(json_data)
for data in dict:
    print(data['PublicIpAddress'])
```

Comment: Not sure if I phrased my question correctly, I need : jsonOutput = select publicIpAadress, privateIpaddress from json_input_file. The 2 fields are for reference, that must be included in final output while others be discarded.

Comment: For that still you have to walk through the JSON loaded into the dictionary like I mentioned in my answer... parse the exact fields and create new dictionary set accordingly... after that, the next step is convert that dictionary result set into JSON using command json.dumps(result_set)